# Setting up multiple video streams with publishing points for clients

Tags: linux, video, vlc, streaming

Can anyone suggest if this is viable on Linux? I have searched and found many many results using VLC but nothing that matches previous Windows Media Services on Windows Server 2008 that we were using.

1. Needs to support push streams from multiple clients - all windows based
2. Setting up channels (publishing points) so clients can stream live video

So clients can use VLC or any other software that can push the stream to the linux server and the server will broadcast it to the world.

I hope this is the correct place to ask this :)

Answer (score 2):

If the protocol in question is [Microsoft Media Server (MMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server), it might not be possible to set it up in Linux.

However, if the clients can switch to [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), you can setup an nginx server compiled with [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) and setup channels where clients can stream.

(Relevant) features that the module supports:

> - Live streaming of video/audio
> - Video on demand FLV/MP4, playing from local filesystem or HTTP
> - Stream relay support for distributed streaming: push & pull models
> - Recording streams in multiple FLVs
> - H264/AAC support
> - Online transcoding with FFmpeg
> - HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) support
> - HTTP callbacks (publish/play/record/update etc)
> - Running external programs on certain events (exec)
> - HTTP control module for recording audio/video and dropping clients
> - Proved to work with Wirecast,FMS,Wowza,
> - JWPlayer,FlowPlayer,StrobeMediaPlayback, ffmpeg,avconv,rtmpdump,flvstreamer and many more

Check the GitHub page for more details.

(This should be migrated to superuser)

Comment: Thanks kedar. Protocol is not important. They'll stream what we provide and there's always ways to convert at client end so I will check this out hopefully today. Sounds promising. Please feel free to migrate to SuperUser @mods

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for something like this a long time ago. Had no luck even after speaking to many experts. I ended up installing virtualbox with windows server 2003 and forwarding all necessary ports to it.

I didn't notice much speed drop either for upto 50 viewers. It's not the answer but it's one alternative and half solution.